# How to solve: locked out of sudoer rights and root account on Arch linux of RPi

Tags: archlinux, sudo, root

I disabled the root login on Arch Linux installed in my RPi without putting my own user account into sudoers. Now I'm prevented from recovering root login. I understand one can use liveCD or GRUB to recover the root, but I'm not sure they are feasible on RPi. Anyone has an idea how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot in advance ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Take the SD card and plug it into your PC, navigate to SD card "/etc/sudoer" and write your name.
Plug card back into Pi and go

Comment: You need to add a bit more than your username... see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/113416/178596)